# Jquery Datatable Pagination not working

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am working with `JQuery DataTable` and fetching data from server and it is working fine except of Pagination. when I click next it fetches next result but when I click previous then also it returns next result not previous. I have debugged the code and found that sEcho is getting incremented by one each time. Also whenever I redraw Table it send request on server and fetching next result.

my code is for updating `sEcho` :

```
sEcho = request.getParameter("sEcho");
```

What is wrong not getting.

My DataTable code is

```
$lmTable = $('#datatable').dataTable( {
         "bProcessing": true,
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": url,

        "iDisplayLength": 10,
        "bFilter":true,
        "bSort": false,
});
```

Comment: could you add the datatables definition? The code were you initialize the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on every request to the server, the value of `sEcho` is updated and sent to the server. 

i.e. on `Next`, `Previous` button clicks too.

This `sEcho` acts like a token to make a reference with the returned values.

So while returning the array via the `url`, make sure the same `sEcho` value is retuned.

Eg: Form data

```
sEcho:1
iColumns:7
sColumns:
.....
```

Returned values should be like -

```
{"sEcho":1,"iTotalRecords":3,"iTotalDisplayRecords":3 ......
```

The `sEcho` sent and `sEcho` received should be same. Next time may be `2` is sent, so `2` should be received.

I hope it helps someone.